# codeigniter mssql query result to mail

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to send email by using codeigniter and the message body will contain the mssql query result.

i don't understand what to do in this situation. also tried. mssql_row_assoc(). but it is sending only one row through mail.

**Code:**

```
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($query)){

    $this->email->message( "<table border='1' style='width:100%; height:auto;'>
    <tr>
       <td>Date</td>
       <td>Name</td>
       <td>Department</td>
        <td>Time</td>
    </tr>  <tr>
    <td>".$row['emp_valid_date']."</td>
    <td>".$row['emp_valid_name']."</td>
    <td>".$row['emp_valid_dept']."</td><td>".
     $row['emp_valid_time']."</td>
     </tr>"
    );
}
```

need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a table first and storing it in a variable then add it to `$this -> email -> messsage`

Example:

```
$data = "<table border='1' style='width:100%; height:auto;'>";

while($row = mssql_fetch_array($query)){

    $data .= "
   <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Department</td>
      <td>Time</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>".$row['emp_valid_date']."</td>
      <td>".$row['emp_valid_name']."</td>
      <td>".$row['emp_valid_dept']."</td>
      <td>".$row['emp_valid_time']."</td>
   </tr>";

}

$data .= "</table>";

$this->email->message($data);
```